# How could an object get a reference to a class that is in a different (and unreferenced) assembly?

Tags: c#, serialization, project-reference

I have two projects: A/B. Project A is the project that contains all of the winforms which are bound to objbects in B (logic items)

A has an object of type 
A.Form

B has objects of type
B.Serializer
B.Logic

Now, A has a reference to B (but B does not have a reference to A) and A.Form contains a member variable of type B.Logic. At some point, when all of the data is stored in B.Logic I try to save this object to disk by calling B.Serializer(B.Logic).

At this point I get an error when serializing saying that A.From is not marked as serializable.

But the project B has NO reference to A at ALL and even if it did SOMEHOW have a member referencing A.Form, it shouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual culprit here is things like events (in `B.Logic`), or other back-references to external objects. You can mark fields as not for serialization:

```
    [NonSerialized]
    private SomeType foo;
```

or with field-like events:

```
    [field: NonSerialized]
    public event EventHandler Bar;
```

As an aside - from the description, I assume that you are using `BinaryFormatter`; personally, I have reservations about this - it is [very brittle](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/03/obfuscation-serialization-and.html). I'd suggest something non-implementation-specific; `XmlSerializer`, [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/), [Json.NET](http://www.codeplex.com/Json), etc.

Comment: Yes, Jon skeet forwarded me to protobuf-net and I'd like to implement it but the time constraints are a bit prohibitive for at least another month at work. I'll see if it's events causing the problem and get back to you.

Comment: You sir, are an eagle amongst turkeys. Thank you. It was indeed an event that was being serialized.